# I get this error " Cannot read property 'getBBox' of null " and I couldn't understand why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to scale a svg part when onmouseover and rescale to previous size onmouseout

Cannot read property 'getBBox' of null

```
D=document;
var lib = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
D.
function magnify(scale,x){  x.setAttribute("transform","matrix(1.5 0 0 1 0 0)");
}
function minimize(x){   x.setAttribute("transform","matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)");
}

function getCenter(selection)
{   bbox=D.getElementById("#"+selection).getBBox();
    return[bbox.x + bbox.width/2,bbox.y + bbox.height/2];
}
function reCoor(scale, x)
{
        var coor = getCenter(x);
        var newX=x[0].width*(1-scale);
        var newY=x[1].height*(1-scale);

        var output = "matrix(" + scale + " 0 0 " + scale + " " + newX + " " + newY +")";

        return[output];
}
```

**[MyFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufuk_akoguz/ucfxkuf6)**

Comment: In `document.getElementById(element)`, element does not need `#` in javascript.

Comment: So this is very helpfull

Comment: Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: I ask a question you vote me minus are you? in some platforms (firefox, ie) '#' might be used.

Comment: I did not vote. Nor negative nor positive. Don't make assumptions.

Comment: sorry I'm new at stackoverflow thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounding box of any element by calling [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

```
var rect = document.getElementById("myElement").getBoundingClientRect();
```

That will return an object with left, top, width and height fields.

Comment: thank you for help but same problem still remains. I remove "#" as you tell me and use the method as you show. I suppose problem is not like seen to be.

Comment: In the fiddle there is no function calling `reCoor`, so noone calles `getCenter`. If I call reCoor, and I comment non working functions, my solution works (see console output): http://jsfiddle.net/ucfxkuf6/2/